# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'replace' with Tkinter and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, httplib2

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import httplib2

soup = BeautifulSoup('html.parser', features="lxml")

#Creation Objet Tkinter#

window = tk.Tk()

#DefinitionTailleObjet#

window.title("Python Tkinter Text Box")
window.minsize(300,200)
label = ttk.Label(window, text = "Entrez l'URL")
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

#DefinitionDeLaTailleObjet#

def Valide():

    http = httplib2.Http()
    status, response = http.request('nameEntered.get')

    for link in bs.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser',parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            print(link['href'])


#Alogrithme Derriere le bouton#
name = tk.StringVar()
nameEntered = ttk.Entry(window, width = 50, textvariable = name)
nameEntered.pack
nameEntered.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
 
button = ttk.Button(window, text = "Validé", command = Valide)
button.grid(column= 0, row = 3)
 
window.mainloop()
```

Here is my code; I'm trying to test a site that the user inputs, then it takes all the links one by one and tests one by one if they work or not, but I'm stuck because there's a problem with the var I think. Please help.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in the line

`status, response = http.request('nameEntered.get')`

You are passing here a hard-coded string to the `http.request()`-function.
Actually, you want to read the content of the textfield, I assume.
Therefore, you need to call `nameEntered.get()` and pass its return value to the function `http.request` in the function named `Valide`, like so

`status, response = http.request(nameEntered.get())`

More descriptive (but equivalent) is this:

```
# Reads the content of the textfield
url = nameEntered.get()
# Queries the URL
status, response = http.request(url)
```

Comment: Holy ! thanks it worked , i did forgot the () , the explanation was very clear ! and my mistake was pretty obvious , thank you again so much